# Android xml Array returning 0 for getIndexCount()

Tags: android, xml, arrays

i'm storing data in an xml array in this fashion

```
<resources>
    <array name="myarray">
        <item>
            <item>attribute1</item>
            <item>attribute2</item>
            <item>and so on</item>
        </item>
        <item>
            <item>attribute1</item>
            <item>attribute2</item>
            <item>and so on</item>
        </item>
        <item>
            <item>attribute1</item>
            <item>attribute2</item>
            <item>and so on</item>
        </item>
    </array>
</resources>

// in program
TypedArray array = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.myarray);
```

when i call array.getIndexCount() in the program it returns 0, what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. According to the android docs:

```
  <resources>
  <string-array name="planets_array">
    <item>Mercury</item>
    <item>Venus</item>
    <item>Earth</item>
    <item>Mars</item>
  </string-array>
  </resources>
```

To get this resource"

```
Resources res = getResources();
String[] planets = res.getStringArray(R.array.planets_array);
```

[This may help..](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html)